# VBA: Open Document based on Cell Value with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still new to VBA so  I'm looking for advise to accomplish the following task:
I Have a cell `A1` and two `Checkboxes (Serverbox1 & Localbox2)`

`A1` is a Pulldown menu with values like Apple1, Banana1 etc... which represent excel file names. Excel should open the picked file  and exporting a cell or a range, for example `A2` from `WB1` to `WB2` by clicking the Export Button.

`Private Sub exportData_Click()`

`Dim WB1 as Workbook`

`Dim WB2 as Workbook`

`Server="C:\Server\Apple1.xls"`

`Local="C:\Local\Apple1.xls"`

`Set WS1=ThisWorkBook`

`Set WB1=ActiveWorkbook`

`WS2=WB2.Sheets(1)`

`Set WB2=Workbooks.Open(Server` OR `Local)`
Somehow that needs to changes automatically.

So that  `Set WB2=Workbooks.Open(Server)`only applies 
If `A1 = Apple1 & Serverbox.value = true & Localbox2.value= false`

And `Set WB2=Workbooks.Open(Local)` only applies `If A1 = Apple1 & Serverbox.value = false & Localbox2.value= true`

Once the file is open it would continue to copy data to `Apple1.xls` or `Banana1.xls` based on the input above.

`ws2.range("A2")=ws1.range("A2")`

I dont need to worry about auto saving anything, it will be a manual process (preferred).
I appreciate any help!

Comment: The file locations are mutually exclusive; radio buttons or a dropdown would have been a better idea than checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas you can use. You'll have to update your code in a couple of places.

```
Server="C:\Server\" & A1 & ".xls" 'Get the filename from Cell A1

Local="C:\Local\" & A1 & ".xls"   'Get the filename from Cell A1


If (Serverbox.value = true & Localbox2.value= false) Then
    WB2=Workbooks.Open(Server) 
End If

If (Serverbox.value = false & Localbox2.value= true) Then
    WB2=Workbooks.Open(Local) 
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped me a lot and opened my eyes to a different approach for this problem.

Comment: Excellent. That is basically what I was trying to do.